Time period of V1 and V2 signal the integrator and schmitt trigger
Hello I have tried to solve this circuit several times and i cant figure out what i did wrong.
You guys give me some tips.
This is circuit with 2 op amp (2 stages) first one is schmitt trigger and the second one the integrator. Very simple actually but there is a zener diode to limited the upper saturation voltage (i guess).

The characteristic zener and all circuit as follow below
Forward bias Zener: \$0.5V\$
reverse breakdown voltage Zener: \$5V\$
The op amp has the power supply as follow
\$Vcc = 7.5V\$
\$Vee = -7.5V\$
Mark the correct answer about the time period of signals \$V_1\$ and \$V_2\$.
a) 2.2 ms
b) 4 ms
c) 11 ms
d) 12.1 ms
e) 22 ms
My attempt:
Consider that the initial op amp is negative saturated would be \$V1 = -7.5\$ but due to zener the forward bias V1 will be \$-0.5V\$
So the \$V_2\$ is integrator
$$V_2(t) = -\dfrac{1}{RC}\int_0^t V_1(\tau) d\tau = -1000\cdot t\cdot V_1 = 500\cdot t$$
So,
Consider that the \$V_{th}\$ voltage threshold (schmitt trigger) is:
$$V_{th} = \dfrac{V_1+V_2}{2}<0$$
to negative saturated op amp
$$\dfrac{-0.5+500\cdot t}{2}<0\Rightarrow t<1ms$$
to \$t>1ms\$
the op amp is positive saturated: \$V_1 = 5V\$ (zener limitator)
$$V_2(t) = -\dfrac{1}{RC}\int_0^t V_1(\tau) d\tau + V_2(t<1ms) = -5000\cdot t+0.5$$
Consider again that the \$V_{th}\$ voltage threshold (schmitt trigger) is:
$$V_{th} = \dfrac{V_1+V_2}{2}>0\Rightarrow \dfrac{5-5000\cdot t + 0.5}{2}>0\Rightarrow t< 1.1ms$$
After this the cycle repeat again. So the period is
\$0<t<1ms\$ (\$V_1 = -0.5V; \quad V_2 = 500\cdot t\$)
\$1ms<t<1.1ms\$ (\$V_1 = 5V; \quad V_2 = -5000\cdot t+0.5V\$)
Doesnt match any answer (answer C is the correct accordly the book)

setup
Here's your schematic, with added annotations:
\$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\$
We'll assume a very snappy Schmitt trigger and ignore start-up details. Instead, just assume this has been running for a long time.
We want to find out the repeating time period.
applied logic
There are two possible states for \$V_1\$ (assuming the Schmitt Trigger has sufficient output impedance while also having sufficient output current compliance):

\$+5\:\text{V}\$ (\$D_{_\text{Z}}\$ is avalanching and holding the output to its specified zener voltage.)
\$-500\:\text{mV}\$ (\$D_{_\text{Z}}\$ is clamping the Schmitt Trigger output to its specified forward-biased voltage.)

\$V_1\$ is tied to one side of \$R\$. The other side of \$R\$ is tied to a virtual ground (maintained by the integrator opamp.)
In case (1) \$I_{_\text{R}}=I_{_1}=\frac{5\:\text{V}-0\:\text{V}}{500\:\Omega}=10\:\text{mA}\$. That's \$+10\:\text{mA}\$ in the downward direction.
In case (2) \$I_{_\text{R}}=I_{_2}=\frac{-500\:\text{mV}-0\:\text{V}}{500\:\Omega}=-1\:\text{mA}\$. That's \$+1\:\text{mA}\$ in the upward direction.
To switch the Schmitt Trigger, the node between \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$ must cross \$0\:\text{V}\$ (in either direction.)
In case (1) this happens when \$V_2\$ reaches \$-5\:\text{V}\$ (as \$V_1=+5\:\text{V}\$.)
In case (2) this happens when \$V_2\$ reaches \$+500\:\text{mV}\$ (as \$V_1=-500\:\text{mV}\$.)
This means that \$V_2\$ swings between \$-5\:\text{V}\$ and \$+500\:\text{mV}\$, for a total dynamic range of \$\vert\Delta V\vert=5.5\:\text{V}\$.
In case (1) the time period is \$t_{_1}=\vert\Delta V\vert\cdot\frac{C}{\vert I_{_1}\vert}=5.5\:\text{V}\cdot \frac{2\:\mu\text{F}}{10\:\text{mA}}=1.1\:\text{ms}\$.
In case (2) the time period is \$t_{_2}=\vert\Delta V\vert\cdot\frac{C}{\vert I_{_2}\vert}=5.5\:\text{V}\cdot \frac{2\:\mu\text{F}}{1\:\text{mA}}=11\:\text{ms}\$.
The sum is \$t_{_1}+t_{_2}=1.1\:\text{ms}+11\:\text{ms}=12.1\:\text{ms}\$. So I would select answer D.
However, if instead you were told that the forward voltage for \$D_{_\text{Z}}\$ was an ideal \$0\:\text{V}\$ (and you were not told that, but something quite specifically different than it), then \$\vert\Delta V\vert=5\:\text{V}\$ and then this would work out to \$t_{_1}+t_{_2}=1\:\text{ms}+10\:\text{ms}=11\:\text{ms}\$. And that would suggest answer C.
But you were specifically told that the forward voltage of the zener wasn't \$0\:\text{V}\$, but was instead \$500\:\text{mV}\$.
So I don't see how answer C works out. I do see why both \$11\:\text{ms}\$ and \$12.1\:\text{ms}\$ were offered as possible answers. I think it's obvious that they wanted to offer two alternates that their more attentive students might find, so they could separate out the ones more able to take all the factors into account from those who might over-simplify.
But I think the one creating the answer key's pick was one of the latter.

I2 is quasi 1.6 mA in place of 1 mA ... t2 is shorter than 11 ms ... quasi 7.5 ms. (simulated with Zener 5.1 V). Vdiode is quasi -0.8 V.

@Antonio51 I chose not to simulate because the question uses behavioral definitions and it would take me too long to make sure that I developed models that would reflect the problem statement behavior. Not sure if it helps anyone in deciding between C or D to get results of 7.5 ms. And it doesn't help the OP work out why C was given as an answer.

ok. It was just a mean of verifying if C was the answer ... Simulation does not help in this case.

@Antonio51 Yeah. I gave it a moment's thought, since I do like to verify what I write when possible. But imagine that the Schmitt Trigger's output has a very low impedance -- say 10 milliOhms. Then if it drives to the negative rail the zener diode would be forced to have a huge forward biased voltage and therefore unsightly currents, too. Anyway, after imagining that kind of horror, I just threw away the whole idea of simulating, at all.

Thank u @periblepsis. just again representing the information that the forward voltage of the zener diode is in fact 500mV and it is not considered ideal for forward bias. I wonder how cant the see using integrated function instead derivative like u to solve this problem.
